# Is there a way to check which temporary table related to which base table during Alter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, database-administration, alter, mysql-5.7

I am altering 10 tables at a time in MySQL. All queries running in parallel from 10 different sessions.

There are temporary tables created in data directory like:

```
 #sql-ib661-1873552283.ibd
 #sql-ib668-1873552287.ibd
 #sql-ib689-1873552292.ibd
 #sql-ib685-1873552291.ibd
 #sql-ib7856-1873552274.ibd
 #sql-ib657-1873552278.ibd
 #sql-ib586-1873552272.ibd
 #sql-ib669-1873552288.ibd
 #sql-ib626-1873552276.ibd
 #sql-ib667-1873552286.ibd
```

How we can check which temporary file belongs to which table's alter command ?
Because i am checking the progress of alter command from the size of these temporary tables.

Is there any mapping or naming conventions to check ?

Comment: I suspect the first number is the process ID that shows up in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`

Comment: Just check, this is not the process id. something else.

Comment: @Barmar that's the internal table id, see https://twindb.com/temporary-table-naming-scheme-in-5-6-and-before/

Answer (score 1):

If you have mysql v5.7.9 or newer, then you can use the [sys.processlist or sys.session](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-processlist.html) views' [progress](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-schema-progress-reporting.html) field to monitor the progress of long running statements.

> Assuming that the required instruments and consumers are enabled, the progress column of these views shows the percentage of work completed for stages that support progress reporting.

Comment: Which instruments need to enable for alter command monitoring ?
I am modifying a column..

Comment: The linked documentation on the progress field tells you that.